# Opendaylight Export/Import using Daexim doesnt transition to "Complete" state

Tags: backup, opendaylight

We are performing online export/import using "Daexim". We are scheduling export job and checking its status using

```
http://<controller-ip>:<restconf-port>/restconf/operations/data-export-import:status-export
```

This URL used to return "complete" status till "Boron", but in Nitrogen we observed the state transitions from "scheduled" -> "in-progress" -> "initial". We are not getting "complete" state after "in-progress".

Please let us know how to identify the status of export/import job.

**Export URL**

```
https://<odl-node>/restconf/operations/data-export-import:schedule-export/
```

**Payload**

```
{
   "input": {
     "data-export-import:run-at": 500
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This most probably indicates that the import failed, for whatever reason.  have you checked the karaf.log for any ERROR related log entries in general, and specifically anything that looks like it could provide you details about what could have failed during the import?

BTW you can get more direct developer support on the mailing list of ODL's daexim project on https://lists.opendaylight.org/mailman/listinfo/daexim-dev.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately we didnt notice any error. Although we dont get "complete" status, we noticed json files to be created under <KARAF_HOME>/daexim. We also tried "import" of those files in another setup, and they were successful.